# Issue to extract raster pixel values in different elevation zones in R

Tags: raster, rgdal

I have large daily datasets in raster format. I want to calculate total number of pixels based on values in different polygons in a single shapefile. The shapefile is STRM DEM 90 meter classified 24 elevation zones. These 24 elevation zones representing 24 polygons in single shapefile. I want to check how many pixels occupied by each polygon.

Primarily, I need to check the total number of pixels based on following values (200,210,240,250) in each polygon and finally store it into CSV.

I already developed code: But facing issue by end.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
mod = raster("MOYDGL06_Maximum_Snow_Extent_2004097.tif")
shp= readOGR("Gilgit_DEM_24.shp")
mod_ext =  extract(mod,shp,df=T,na.rm=T)
mod_mask = mask(mod,shp)
plot(r2,axes = TRUE,ext = extent(shp))
r3_200    =  rasterToPoints(mod_mask,function(x){ x ==200 },spatial = TRUE)
r3_210    =  rasterToPoints(mod_mask,function(x){ x ==210 },spatial = TRUE)
r3_240    =  rasterToPoints(mod_mask,function(x){ x ==240 },spatial = TRUE)
r3_250    =  rasterToPoints(mod_mask,function(x){ x ==250 },spatial = TRUE)
r3_200_1          =    raster::intersect(shp,r3_200)
write.csv(r3_200_1,file = 'r2_extract_gilgit.csv')
```

Image and R code available in [this link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SI_9uXBMJTklRUKBTs2DrSVpMeuQ--ms?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example. That is, you should use some example data that come with R, or that you create in code.

Comment: Dear Robert, I already provided R code and raster images in the description.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, that is, not depend on data that needs to be downloaded.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you I found a solution...